# Beta decay in Au-198 element

Tags: radiation

Book "Atoms, radiation, and radiatuon protection" shows decay modes in appendix.
In case of Au-198, there is only one type of decay β-.
β- : 0.255max (avg 0.079) (1%)
0.961max (avg 0.315) (99%)

γ : 0.412(96%)
0.676(1%)
The difference between max β- value
0.961 - 0.255 = 0.706 doesn't appear in γ ray but there is 0.676.
Is this measurement error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the decay chart from the [KAERI website](https://pripyat.mit.edu/KAERI/) which shows that your data was missing one of the possible $\beta^-$ decay modes.

[image]